# Unable to set Size defaults in Swift 2.0 Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am in the process of migrating a game to IOS 9, Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.3. In the following section I am attempting to set the default anchorPoint t0 0.5. However it doesn't want to work.

The follow code is just inside my GameScene:SKScene class file.

```
   override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

I am getting the below error:

> fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: Are you using the `init(fileNamed:)` initialiser to create an instance of your scene?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write (and initialize all of your own variables):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```